# Spark Structured Streaming NoSuchMethodError with JSON4S: org.json4s.JsonDSL$.pair2Assoc

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

ERROR StateSchemaCompatibilityChecker: Fail to write schema file to file:/tmp/temporary-60e147e4-2a38-4e25-82c8-ac0daf9fc5d7/state/0/0/_metadata/schema
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.json4s.JsonDSL$.pair2Assoc(Lscala/Tuple2;Lscala/Function1;)Lorg/json4s/JsonDSL$JsonAssoc;

```
    
import org.apache.log4j.Level;
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import org.apache.spark.sql.streaming.StreamingQuery;
import org.apache.spark.sql.types.*;

public class App {
        public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
            Logger.getLogger("org").setLevel(Level.ERROR);
            Logger.getLogger("akka").setLevel(Level.ERROR);

            SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                    .builder()
                    .appName("IncidentCountByService")
                    .master("local[*]")
                    .getOrCreate();

            String schemaString = "Id Title Description Service Date";
            StructType schema = new StructType();
            for (String fieldName : schemaString.split(" ")) {
                schema = schema.add(fieldName, DataTypes.StringType);
            }



            Dataset<Row> rowDataset = spark
                    .readStream()
                    .schema(schema)
                    .option("header", "true")
                    .csv("/data/");

            Dataset<Row> incidentCounts = rowDataset
                    .groupBy("Service")
                    .count().alias("Count")
                    .orderBy("Service");


            StreamingQuery query = incidentCounts
                    .writeStream()
                    .outputMode("complete")
                    .format("console")
                    .start();

            query.awaitTermination();
        }


}
```

Id,Title,Description,Service,Date
1,Title_1,Description_1,Service_3,2023-11-20
2,Title_2,Description_2,Service_1,2023-11-3
3,Title_3,Description_3,Service_4,2023-11-27
4,Title_4,Description_4,Service_1,2023-11-6
5,Title_5,Description_5,Service_5,2023-11-4
6,Title_6,Description_6,Service_1,2023-11-30
7,Title_7,Description_7,Service_4,2023-11-2
8,Title_8,Description_8,Service_4,2023-11-22